# Colombia e-visa type for tourism?

Tags: visas, colombia, e-visas, saudi-citizens

I'm Saudi citizen and I would like to apply for e-visa for Colombia, I would like to visit it for tourism for 2 weeks.
https://tramitesmre.cancilleria.gov.co/tramites/enlinea/solicitarVisa.xhtml

They have three classes for the visa in the website:
1.Business  2.Resident  3.Temporary

So I pick Temporary
However, this has about 16 Visa category
from TP-1 to TP-16, I understand some of them for student and another for marriage. But I couldn't know which one is for the tourism.

> TP-1 (Courtesy)
>
> TP-2 (Crew)
>
> TP-3 (Student)
>
> TP-4 (Worker)
>
> TP-5 (Religious)
>
> TP-6​(Cooperative or volunteer of non-profit organization or non-governmental organization (NGO))
>
> TP-7 (Pensioner or Rentista, Partner or Owner of partnership, real estate owner, Independent Activities, medical treatment
>
> TP-8 (For Adoption Procedures; To intervene in judicial or administrative proceedings)
>
> TP-9 (Refugee or Asylee)
>
> TP-10 (Spouse or permanent partner of Colombian national)
>
> TP-11 (Visitor Tourist)
>
> TP-12 (Temporary Visitor)
>
> TP-13 (Technical Visitor)
>
> TP-14 (Transit Visa)
>
> TP-15 (For temporary residence MERCOSUR)
>
> TP-16 (Holiday and Work)

So which one is is the visa for Tourist to Colombia? TP11,TP12 or TP16?

and should I have invite to visit Colombia ?

Comment: Could you copy the 16 and paste them into your question?  One has to submit details (passport number, name, etc) in inder to get to the page you're looking at. Give us all the categories, and we'll be better able to answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're planning to visit for tourism, it's probably not necessary to understand every inapplicable category fully.  That would be helpful for a process of elimination, which you would use if there were no category that seemed to apply, or more than one category that seemed to apply equally.

For a two-week tourist visit with no work involved, however, there is a single best choice among the options, making elimination unnecessary:

> TP-11 (Visitor Tourist)

Comment: It becomes quite clear that TP-11 is indeed the correct category when you look to the Spanish-language descriptions of the [Cancillería](http://www.cancilleria.gov.co/tramites_servicios/visas/clases). +1

Comment: yes, this the closest one. I just want to confirm it, thanks